# How do I represent the content of this UITableCell programmatically using Auto Layout?

Tags: ios, objective-c, cocoa, autolayout, nslayoutconstraint

I have just started using Auto Layout for my latest project and I was wondering what would be the most efficient way of laying out the following table cell:

[image: UITableCell: the various necessary views are shown in black]

Views A and B are both UILabels. C is a fixed size image and the view under A is an image that may or not be present. I am able to easily lay out A, B and C. But if the image under A is present, A's height needs to shrink proportionately and the image needs to fit underneath so that both are centered horizontally in the contentView.

I am trying to lay the entire cell out using code and the Visual Format language and have gotten quite close so far. The only problem is that the A and it's accompanying image aren't centered vertically in the container. You can see how far I have gotten in the image below:

[image: Layout using a combination of the Visual Format Language and some extra constraints]

And here is the code that I am using in my `updateConstraints` method. Note that with this code, I don't get an ambiguous layout:

```
NSDictionary *views = NSDictionaryOfVariableBindings(viewA, viewB, viewC);
    [self.contentView addConstraints:[NSLayoutConstraint constraintsWithVisualFormat:@"H:|-[viewA]-[viewB]-(>=8)-[viewC]-|"
                                                                             options:0
                                                                             metrics:nil
                                                                               views:views]];


    NSDictionary *metrics = @{@"width":@(40.0f), @"height":@(40.0f), @"priority":@(UILayoutPriorityRequired)};

    [viewC addConstraints:[NSLayoutConstraint constraintsWithVisualFormat:@"H:[viewC(==width@priority)]"
                                                                          options:0
                                                                          metrics:metrics
                                                                            views:@{@"viewC": _merchantLogo}]];
    [viewC addConstraints:[NSLayoutConstraint constraintsWithVisualFormat:@"V:[viewC(==height@priority)]"
                                                                          options:0
                                                                          metrics:metrics
                                                                            views:views]];

    [viewA addConstraints:[NSLayoutConstraint constraintsWithVisualFormat:@"H:[viewA(>=75@750)]"
                                                                           options:0
                                                                           metrics:nil
                                                                             views:views]];

    [viewB addConstraints:[NSLayoutConstraint constraintsWithVisualFormat:@"H:[viewB(>=115@500)]"
                                                                          options:0
                                                                          metrics:nil
                                                                            views:views]];

    [self.contentView addConstraints:@[[NSLayoutConstraint constraintWithItem:viewC
                                                                    attribute:NSLayoutAttributeCenterY
                                                                    relatedBy:NSLayoutRelationEqual
                                                                       toItem:self.contentView
                                                                    attribute:NSLayoutAttributeCenterY multiplier:1.0f constant:0.0f],
                                       [NSLayoutConstraint constraintWithItem:viewB
                                                                    attribute:NSLayoutAttributeCenterY
                                                                    relatedBy:NSLayoutRelationEqual
                                                                       toItem:self.contentView
                                                                    attribute:NSLayoutAttributeCenterY multiplier:1.0f constant:0.0f]]];

    if (!viewD) {
        [self.contentView addConstraints:@[[NSLayoutConstraint constraintWithItem:viewA
                                                                        attribute:NSLayoutAttributeCenterY
                                                                        relatedBy:NSLayoutRelationEqual
                                                                           toItem:self.contentView
                                                                        attribute:NSLayoutAttributeCenterY multiplier:1.0f constant:0.0f]]];
    } else {
        [self.contentView addConstraints:[NSLayoutConstraint constraintsWithVisualFormat:@"V:[viewA][viewD]"
                                                                                 options:NSLayoutFormatAlignAllLeft
                                                                                 metrics:nil
                                                                                   views:NSDictionaryOfVariableBindings(viewA, viewD)]];
    }
```

One of my ideas was to put A and the image below it in a container view and then lay them out within that view. But that seems kind of inefficient and I first want to make sure this isn't possible without using a container view.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[image]

So...

```
1.
Format
@"|-[_viewA(<=75)]-[viewB]-[viewC(==60)]-|"
Options
NSLayoutFormatAlignAllTop

2.
Format
@"V:|-[viewA]-[imageView(==10)]-|"
Options
NSLayoutFormatAlignCenterX | NSLayoutFormatAlignAllLeft

3.
Add individual constraints to constrain bottom of image view to bottom of viewB and viewC.
[NSLayotuConstraint constraintWithItem:viewB
                             attribute:NSLayoutAttributeBottom
                             relatedBy:NSLayoutRelationEqual
                                toItem:imageView
                             attribute:NSLayoutAttributeBottom
                            multiplier:1.0
                              constant:0];

and other one...
```

This should give you what you want.

Comment: This is almost perfect! Thanks a bunch. The one thing I had to change was remove 3. in your answer and add a constraint that aligns viewC with the contentView's center Y. The views then become vertically centered in the cell.